# XML file form webserver to android app

Tags: android, xml, authentication, webserver

I'd like to recive a xml file from a webserver.

The data will be insert in a `listView` and the file will be saved in the *assest-folder*.

The app will be authenticated by username and pin-code, like an eMail client.

**I have this code snippet:**

```
XMLReader myReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    myReader.setContentHandler(handler);
    myReader.parse(new InputSource(new URL("www.example.com/xml/test.xml).openStream()));
```

How can I make this in an easy way?.

Thx for your help.

Comment: **"How can I make this in an easy way?"** : Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. Please edit your question and explain more clearly.

Comment: What don't you understand? I asked. How can I recive an xml file easily into the app. After reciving the file it should be saved into assets-folder.